# corona loadRemoteImage loading in another scene

Tags: coronasdk

I am using display.loadRemoteImage to obtain many image from a remote location.

All works fine, but if I click on a button to transition to another scene while 1 (of the many) images is still loading the image gets displayed on the other scene.

I don't want this to happen.

How can I:

1. cancel the loadRemoteImage before gotoScene
2. remove all
   elements in a new scene that do not belong to that scene. I do not
   have an ID since the loadRemoteImage is added into a
   display.newGroup()

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The display.loadRemoteImage() doesn't return an ID that can be used to cancel the download like the network.* functions do.  This API call is just a convenience method around network.request.  Corona Labs has recently published the code for display.loadRemoteImage() to the documentation here:

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/loadRemoteImage.html

You can take that code and modify it so you can cancel the call.

Answer (score 0):

I think its problem of grouping of image which you loaded from loadRemoteImage.

This api will directly load images on scene and comes in front of view. and once you'll switch or remove scene from memory,still it'll stay on view.

You should use network.download for it. it has option to insert your downloaded images on scene groups and you can edit, remove or manipulate with downloaded images.

In networkListener you can insert myImage in your scene groups:
 Here is the code block for it:

```
local function networkListener( event )
        if ( event.isError ) then
                print( "Network error - download failed" )
        elseif ( event.phase == "began" ) then
                print( "Progress Phase: began" )
        elseif ( event.phase == "ended" ) then
                print( "displaying response image file" )
                myImage = display.newImage( event.response.filename, event.response.baseDirectory, 60, 40 )
                myImage.alpha = 0
                transition.to( myImage, { alpha = 1.0 } )
        end
end

local params = {}
        params.progress = true

network.download(
        "http://www.coronalabs.com/demo/hello.png",
        "GET",
        networkListener,
        params,
        "helloCopy.png",
        system.TemporaryDirectory
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can disable the next scene button which loading images from network or you can cancel the download network..